# ¿Cómo iterar en un DataFrame que cumpla con cierta condición de suma y de agrupamiento en Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

En esta ocasión cuento con el siguiente DataFrame "ascend", el cual ordeno de manera ascendente por la columna "GEOCOD_SEG":

```
    ascend = MZ_0806.sort_values(["GEOCOD_SEG"])
    ascend.head(10)

        ID  COD_MZA NRO_VIV DOMINIO TOTAL_VIV  COD_BAR_2     GEOCOD_SEG
    579 0   Mz-001  V-022     2         22         1       080601001001N00x001
    390 0   Mz-002  V-013     2         13         1       080601001001N00x002
    389 0   Mz-003  V-011     2         11         1       080601001001N00x003
    658 0   Mz-004  V-007     2         7          1       080601001001N00x004
    388 0   Mz-005  V-001     2         1          1       080601001001N00x005
    659 0   Mz-006  V-004     2         4          1       080601001001N00x006
    704 0   Mz-007  V-015     2         15         1       080601001001N00x007
    580 0   Mz-008  V-005     2         5          1       080601001001N00x008
    582 0   Mz-001  V-000     2         3          2       080601001002N00x001
    583 0   Mz-002  V-001     2         1          2       080601001002N00x002
```

Lo siguiente es crear una nueva columna "SUM_VIV", en la que se aplicará la suma de los elementos del campo "TOTAL_VIV", agrupado por el campo "COD_BAR_2", y con la ayuda de la función ***transform***, obtendré para cada fila del df original el resultado de la suma total de cada grupo.

```
    ascend['SUM_VIV'] = ascend.groupby('COD_BAR_2')['TOTAL_VIV'].transform(sum)
    ascend.head(10)

        ID  COD_MZA NRO_VIV TOTAL_VIV   COD_BAR_2     GEOCOD_SEG          SUM_VIV
    579 0   Mz-001  V-022       22         1      080601001001N00x001       78
    390 0   Mz-002  V-013       13         1      080601001001N00x002       78
    389 0   Mz-003  V-011       11         1      080601001001N00x003       78
    658 0   Mz-004  V-007       7          1      080601001001N00x004       78
    388 0   Mz-005  V-001       1          1      080601001001N00x005       78
    659 0   Mz-006  V-004       4          1      080601001001N00x006       78
    704 0   Mz-007  V-015       15         1      080601001001N00x007       78
    580 0   Mz-008  V-005       5          1      080601001001N00x008       78
    582 0   Mz-001  V-000       0          2      080601001002N00x001       72
    583 0   Mz-002  V-001       1          2      080601001002N00x002       72
```

Ahora bien.!! lo que busco es poder iterar para cada elemento de cada grupo "COD_BAR_2", sumar los elementos de "TOTAL_VIV" respectivamente, y aplicar una condición de suma <= 50, osea que, habrán grupos que la suma total sera mayor a 50, por lo que necesito sub-dividir estos grupos en base a esta condición de suma. Lo que esperaría obtener seria algo así:

```
    ascend.head(10)

        ID  COD_MZA NRO_VIV TOTAL_VIV   COD_BAR_2     GEOCOD_SEG          SUM_VIV                  
    579 0   Mz-001  V-022       22         1      080601001001N00x001       46
    390 0   Mz-002  V-013       13         1      080601001001N00x002       46
    389 0   Mz-003  V-011       11         1      080601001001N00x003       46
    658 0   Mz-004  V-007       7          1      080601001001N00x004       32
    388 0   Mz-005  V-001       1          1      080601001001N00x005       32
    659 0   Mz-006  V-004       4          1      080601001001N00x006       32
    704 0   Mz-007  V-015       15         1      080601001001N00x007       32
    580 0   Mz-008  V-005       5          1      080601001001N00x008       32
    582 0   Mz-001  V-000       0          2      080601001002N00x001       35
    583 0   Mz-002  V-001       1          2      080601001002N00x002       35
```

Que operación o función necesito aplicar al df en cuestión?? Agradeceré mucho sus valiosos aportes, gracias de antemano.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Data

Cómo el OP no ha indicado que versión de `Python` ¿es? (2 ó 3) y como voy a generar los datos (ligeramente diferentes para que se visualize mejor la solución) mediante `StringIO`, aquí el código para que pueda ser verificado.

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    from StringIO import StringIO   ## Python 2
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO         ## Python 3

# dummy data
data_string = """
ID,COD_MZA,NRO_VIV,TOTAL_VIV,COD_BAR_2,GEOCOD_SEG                      
0,Mz-001,V-022,22,1,080601001001N00x001
0,Mz-002,V-013,13,1,080601001001N00x002
0,Mz-003,V-011,11,1,080601001001N00x003
0,Mz-004,V-007,7,1,080601001001N00x004
0,Mz-005,V-001,1,1,080601001001N00x005
0,Mz-006,V-004,4,1,080601001001N00x006
0,Mz-007,V-015,15,1,080601001001N00x007
0,Mz-008,V-005,5,1,080601001001N00x008
0,Mz-009,V-011,11,1,080601001001N00x009
0,Mz-011,V-022,22,1,080601001001N00x011
"""

data = StringIO(data_string)
ascend = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
```

### Suma Acumulada por Columnas y Límite de Suma Acumulada

`Pandas` ofrece una solución rápida para la primera parte, es decir, sumar mediante categorías (agrupando columnas). También se parte de datos ya ordenados (`ascend = MZ_0806.sort_values(["GEOCOD_SEG"])`)

```
ascend['grupo_temporal_acumulado'] = ascend.groupby('COD_BAR_2')['TOTAL_VIV'].cumsum()

print(ascend)
#     ID COD_MZA NRO_VIV  TOTAL_VIV  COD_BAR_2        GEOCOD_SEG         grupo_temporal_acumulado
#    0  Mz-001   V-022         22          1       080601001001N00x001             22
#    0  Mz-002   V-013         13          1       080601001001N00x002             35
#    0  Mz-003   V-011         11          1       080601001001N00x003             46
#    0  Mz-004   V-007          7          1       080601001001N00x004             53
#    0  Mz-005   V-001          1          1       080601001001N00x005             54
#    0  Mz-006   V-004          4          1       080601001001N00x006             58
#    0  Mz-007   V-015         15          1       080601001001N00x007             73
#    0  Mz-008   V-005          5          1       080601001001N00x008             78
#    0  Mz-009   V-011         11          1       080601001001N00x009             89
#    0  Mz-011   V-022         22          1       080601001001N00x011            111
```

Dado que el `límite` de la `suma acumulada` debe ser `50`, pareciera entonces que el paso anterior es innecesario.

Si se observa en detalle la columna `grupo_temporal_acumulado` hay una `sub agrupación` que debería ser de `50` en `50` o en ciclos repetidos de `50`... muy similar a un "reloj" cada 24 horas es un nuevo día.

Un pequeño ejemplo para mostrar el punto anterior.

```
print( [ hr // 24 for hr in range(72) ])
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

En 72 horas hay 3 días (en ciclos de 24 horas) es decir los primeros 24 0's corresponden al primer día, los 24 números 1's al segundo día y por último los 24 números 2's al tercer día.

Este concepto corresponde al de [aritmética modular](https://es.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic) y la clave está en el operador `//` que `Python` nos ofrece para su computo.

Aquí entonces el código relevante

```
limite_viv = 50
ascend['grupo_temporal'] = ascend.groupby('COD_BAR_2')['TOTAL_VIV'].cumsum() // limite_viv

print(ascend[['COD_BAR_2', 'grupo_temporal_acumulado', 'grupo_temporal']])
#   COD_BAR_2  grupo_temporal_acumulado  grupo_temporal
#           1                        22               0
#           1                        35               0
#           1                        46               0
#           1                        53               1
#           1                        54               1
#           1                        58               1
#           1                        73               1
#           1                        78               1
#           1                        89               1
#           1                       111               2
```

Ya con esta nueva agrupación se puede aplicar una nueva suma acumulada

```
ascend['grupo_limite_acumulado'] = ascend.groupby(['COD_BAR_2','grupo_temporal'])['TOTAL_VIV'].cumsum()

print(ascend[['COD_BAR_2', 'grupo_temporal_acumulado', 'grupo_temporal', 'grupo_limite_acumulado']])
#    COD_BAR_2  grupo_temporal_acumulado  grupo_temporal  grupo_limite_acumulado
#           1                        22               0                      22
#           1                        35               0                      35
#           1                        46               0                      46
#           1                        53               1                       7
#           1                        54               1                       8
#           1                        58               1                      12
#           1                        73               1                      27
#           1                        78               1                      32
#           1                        89               1                      43
#           1                       111               2                      22
```

## Join dataframe Pandas

Si se observa la columna `grupo_limite_acumulado` lo que interesa es su máximo agrupado por `COD_BAR_2` y `grupo_temporal`

```
df_ascend2 = ascend \
                .groupby(['COD_BAR_2','grupo_temporal'])['grupo_limite_acumulado'] \
                .max() \
                .to_frame('SUM_VIV') \
                .reset_index()

print(df_ascend2)
#   COD_BAR_2  grupo_temporal  SUM_VIV
#          1               0       46
#          1               1       43
#          1               2       22
```

Pero como `df_ascend2` no contiene toda la información del dataframe `ascend` hay que vincular ambos dataframes. Afortunadamente `Pandas` contempla un método llamado `merge` para lograr lo anterior.

```
ascend = pd.merge(ascend, df_ascend2, on=['COD_BAR_2','grupo_temporal'])
```

## Resultado

Como se emplearon columnas auxiliares y temporales las podemos eliminar para generar el reporte final

```
borrar_columnas = ['grupo_temporal_acumulado','grupo_temporal','grupo_limite_acumulado']
ascend.drop(borrar_columnas, inplace=True, axis=1)

print(ascend)
#    ID COD_MZA NRO_VIV  TOTAL_VIV  COD_BAR_2          GEOCOD_SEG         SUM_VIV
#    0  Mz-001   V-022         22          1      080601001001N00x001       46
#    0  Mz-002   V-013         13          1      080601001001N00x002       46
#    0  Mz-003   V-011         11          1      080601001001N00x003       46
#    0  Mz-004   V-007          7          1      080601001001N00x004       43
#    0  Mz-005   V-001          1          1      080601001001N00x005       43
#    0  Mz-006   V-004          4          1      080601001001N00x006       43
#    0  Mz-007   V-015         15          1      080601001001N00x007       43
#    0  Mz-008   V-005          5          1      080601001001N00x008       43
#    0  Mz-009   V-011         11          1      080601001001N00x009       43
#    0  Mz-010   V-007          7          1      080601001001N00x010       43
#    0  Mz-011   V-022         22          1      080601001001N00x011       22
```

> Como se mencionó al inicio, los datos originales los alteré ligeramente, para que se aprecie mejor la agrupación por aritmética modular, en tal sentido, debe funcionar con los datos originales que proporcionó el OP. Asimismo se asume que la columna `TOTAL_VIV` es de tipo entero y no existen `NAs`. Esto último al no ser precisado por el OP, no ha sido resuelto en esta respuesta, no obstante `Pandas` permite saltarlos de ser necesario con [skipna=True](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Comment: Muchas Gracias estimado @HubertRonald..!!! Excelente procedimiento.!! Me aporto mucho en la solución, te agradezco, y para la próxima consulta, daré mas detalles de los datos. Saludos.!!!